# It doesn't take my CSS code on some html tags

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem that I honestly don't understand why. I am attaching the code, so I can explain it step by step

```
<body>
  <h1>Versioni Mago Dei Clienti</h1>
  <form class="form" method="post" action="">
        <label for="nome_cliente">Nome cliente:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nome_cliente" name="nome_cliente"><br><br>
        <label for="versione_mago">Versione Mago:</label>
        <input type="text" id="versione_mago" name="versione_mago"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Estrai dati">
  </form>
  <div>
    <table>
      <p style="color: red;">Per cercare una versione specifica, usare gli id sotto riportati</p>
      <tr><td>ID Mago</td><td>Versione</td></tr>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>3.3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td><td>3.3.0.HF2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td><td>3.4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>4</td><td>3.4.1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>5</td><td>3.5</td></tr>
      <tr><td>6</td><td>3.5.1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>7</td><td>3.6</td></tr>
      <tr><td>8</td><td>3.6.1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>9</td><td>4.0</td></tr>
      <tr><td>10</td><td>4.0.0.HF2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>11</td><td>4.0.1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>12</td><td>4.1</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
    <hr>
      <?php
        // includi il file data.php
        include '../assets/codice.php';
      ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, the css code is linked correctly, as you can see, I wish I could change the css of the p tag, but I don't understand why it doesn't get me? I don't think there are other codes that can bother.

style.css:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

th {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  color: darkgoldenrod;
}
.form{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 20px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

body{
  background-color: rgba(229, 209, 234, 0.585);
}
p{
  color: red;
}
```

Here I leave you the photo of the page, as you can see the css is correctly linked, but why doesn't the paragraph color?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohI7m.jpg

1. I tried moving the code

   ```
   p{
     color: red;
   }
   ```

   to the top of the .css file, nothing has changed
2. I also tried with id and class, nothing changed

   ```
   <p class="paragrafo">Per cercare una versione specifica, usare gli id sotto riportati</p>

   .paragrafo{
     color: red;
   }
   ```
3. By doing this, it works correctly; why?

   ```
   <p style="color: red;">Per cercare una versione specifica, usare gli id sotto riportati</p>
   ```

UPDATE: I feel like crying... I cleared my browser cache - it worked.

Comment: I've thrown your code into a JSfiddle and it's working like you intended. The paragraph is red. https://jsfiddle.net/07zkvpso/ -- So maybe there IS something else changing the color. Any JavaScript? Any CSS with !important statement? Can you create a minimal reproducable version of your code which includes the problem?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to use the browser developer tools to figure out what rules are being applied and which are being overridden. It sounds like you have a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) problem.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting the exact code I have on the link you sent me and it works, I don't understand why it doesn't work for me, I don't have javascript files, the only files I have are .php files which however only manage the 'extracting data from the db, they don't nothing about style. I also checked the p tag with f12, and actually no style is detected, I don't understand why. By creating a version of the project what do you mean?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, ignore all answers and comments until you have fixed this as different browsers may be more or less tolerant about this syntax error. You may not have a p element as the direct child of a table element. It's often a good idea to put your code through a validator - e.g. this https://validator.w3.org/ picked up the error.

Comment: but the problem remains the same, whether I leave the p tag in the <table> or if I insert it only in the <body> it still doesn't take the style

Comment: UPDATE: I feel like crying.........I cleared my browser cache......it worked. Im so fucking stupid. Ty y all I wish you a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've something over-riding the p css tag, your code works fine in the demo using what you've provided, see https://jsfiddle.net/fe8hryca/ the below line shows in red as expected.

```
Per cercare una versione specifica, usare gli id sotto riportati
```

If it's text coloring maybe try wrapping the text in a span as a work-around.

- edit - corrected issue pointed out by dantheman

Comment: The link you provided shows that 'name' is not to be used on p tags.

Comment: And but still the ovverriding, wouldn't it be enough to put the id in the p tag? In this way
<p id="prova">Per cercare una versione specifica, usare gli id sotto riportati</p>
#prova{
 color: red;
}
the id should surpass all other style.. I think it was so'